# Vue + html-webpack-plugin not load index.html generated

Tags: webpack, vue.js, html-webpack-plugin, vue-loader

I try to use HtmlWebPackPlugin to generate my index.html so...

1. I init a new project `vue init webpack-simple#1.0 vue-html-webpack`
2. Install `npm i -D html-webpack-plugin`
3. Rename `index.html` to `entry-template.html`
4. Configure `webpack.config.js` ..

I add ..

```
  plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'entry-template.html',
        environment: process.env.NODE_ENV
      })
    ],
```

But web I start the app `npm run dev`, the 404 is returned (I suppose is not finding the `index.html`)

My `entry-template.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>GitSkills</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Full [source here](https://vue-html-webpack-ogqlguavxx.now.sh/_src)**

Result -> https://vue-html-webpack-ogqlguavxx.now.sh/

### Question

How can I use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) with Vue 1.0?

Comment: Can you provide a link to clone the repo?

Comment: Yep.. https://github.com/Ridermansb/vue-html-plugin-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HtmlWebpackPlugin` uses the globally configured loaders to process the template when not defined differently. In your case this results in the `vue-html-loader` handling your `entry-template.html`. Probably this is the reason, your template html is not processed correctly. Please have a look at the [docs for the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md#2-setting-a-loader-directly-for-the-template) about the way the loaders are handled.

Does specifying the loader directly work in your case?

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: '!!html!entry-template.html',
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV
  })
],
```

For details on the syntax, please see the [docs about loaders order](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#loader-order) and overwriting them.

UPDATE:

The `vue-html-loader` is an extension of the original `html-loader` and doesn't seem to cause the problem here. From your webpack output, I saw that you are using the `publicPath` property which controls the base path to be used when serving your content. This is not the path of your files on your disk but the path in the url where your content should be served from. So your setup already works when you are visiting `localhost:8080/dist`. Omitting the publicPath property makes it serve from the root path.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  ...
```

Also, when using the router, you should add a router-outlet to your template such that the content of your templates (e.g. login) can be included in the main template (which I guess is `app`).

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have loader for HTML `{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'vue-html' }` , I tried to change HtmlWebpackPlugin configuratiion to to `template: '!!html!entry-template.html',` but the same error occurs

Comment: Did you install the loader with npm? Could you please add the console output of running webpack to your question?

Comment: You can see the project here.. https://github.com/Ridermansb/vue-html-plugin-problem

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answers here and about two days of research, on the same problem, it turns out that this issue is related specifically to the fact that the webpack-development-server does not write files to your local file system and instead writes its files to *MEMORY ONLY*.

You ***SHOULD*** be able to properly generate files wth Html-Webpack-Plugin when you run the default webpack build command (**NOT** the WDS / Webpack-Development-Server) with:

```
webpack
```

Keep in mind you must be in the project directory. Alternately for those using vue.js Webpack-simple project (https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/tree/master/template) you can use the npm scripts  that come with the Vue.js sample (located inside of your package.json) via:

```
npm run build
```

If all goes well you will notice that the files ARE written to the directory as you would have thought they should be, but were not, when using Webpack-Development-Server (again this does not work because WDS writes to memory and not the local file system).

You can see this StackOverflow question also runs into the issue when using the base Vue.js Webpack project:
[html-webpack-plugin not inject js file into index.html when using webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585680/html-webpack-plugin-not-inject-js-file-into-index-html-when-using-webpack-dev-se)

I stumbled onto this answer when reading the above question since the user mentions:

> "If I run webpack or npm run build, the js file is injected successfully. Can html-webpack-plugin also inject js file into index.html when I'm in localhost?"